# How do I use StatsD with Zend Framework application?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, statsd

In essense I am curious about how other people do that, specifically -- do you wrap StatsD example PHP client in your own class? Where to you store configuration for it? Any gotchas for using statsd in ZF based application?

Thank you!

PS: Since I am using both ZF1 and ZF2 this question pertains to both versions of ZF.

Answer (score 0):

There are some PHP clients available for Statsd - have a look at http://packagist.org and search for "statsd". The added benefit is that you'd be able to install anything you select via Composer.

How to store configuration is completely up to you and how you are doing it already in your application.